# multicolumn for ul lists inside lists css

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have certain ul lists in my html page.

```
<div class="multicolumns">
  <ul>
    <li>Main 1</li>
    <li>Main 2
      <ul>
        <li>Sub 1</li>
        <li>Sub 2</li>
        <li>Sub 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Main 3</li>
    <li>Main 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I used multicolumn css to automatically make the list in three columns. But the problem is the sub lists break to new column. It should be under the main head. For that i tried the following css.

```
.multicolumns {
  -moz-column-count: 3; 
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -moz-column-rule: 0px double #666;
  -webkit-column-count: 3; 
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-rule: 0px double #666;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 10px;
  column-rule: 0px double #666;;
}  

.multicolumns li {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Expected result:

[image]

But it's not working. How to fix this?

Comment: Can you create a demo on Jsfiddle and your question is not clear?

Comment: Please verify http://jsfiddle.net/DpKNS/. The sub list should display under main 2. It shouldn't break apart.

Comment: Can you add a picture of expected UI?

Answer (score 0):

Your example works in Chrome for me.

Otherwise according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn most browsers don't support this.

Aside from that you are using the wrong property names. It's called `break-inside` and not `column-break-inside`, thus it would be `-moz-break-inside` if Firefox would support it. Only Webkit uses the non standard `-webkit-column-break-inside`.

Comment: FYI, Firefox now supports `page-break-inside` to control breaks on columns. Kinda stupid, but it was the only way I could get it working for columns for something I had worked on.